# Example of a complete non-projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am attempting to solve hartshorne's exercises. I am stuck at the exercise 7.13(b) of chapter 2 which is the following

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of char $\neq$ 2.Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2_{k}$ be a nodal cubic curve $y^2z = x^3 + x^2z$. Then i need to show Pic($C \times \mathbb{A}^1 $) $\cong \mathbb{G}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}$. It has been suggested to use the method of exercise 6.9( which asks to prove as a  part of the problem that Pic($C$) $\cong \mathbb{G}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}$). A hint has been given that if $A$ is a domain then $A[t]^{*} = A^{*}$. I still donot see how to approach the problem. Some more hints or alternative suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you miswrite the title of the question?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Yeah. It seems so now that i look at it. I apologize. Actually this is the title of the problem in hartshorne. What should the title be changed to?

Comment: I see. The point of that exercise is indeed to give an example of a complete non-projective variety, but your question has nothing to do with that a priori. Anyway, Exercise 6.9 shows that $Pic(C)$ fits into a short exact sequence. You might want to write down the analogous short exact sequence for $Pic(C\times \mathbb A^1)$ and then show that this sequence splits. That would give you the first isomorphism. I don't think any part of Exercise 6.9 asks you to prove that $Pic(C) \cong\mathbb G_m$ (as it is false).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar You are right. I meant to write Pic(C) $\cong \mathbb{G}_m \times \mathbb{Z}$ as normalization of C is just $\mathbb{P}^1$. Regarding what you asked me to do. I am having trouble with identifying the kernel of the exact sequence i obtain.